Does Firebase not trigger a Stream in Flutter when something is deleted?
I have two buttons in a custom Flutter class that is the item for a ListView.builder within a Stream that listens to a firebase document.  One button lets me edit a field in a firebase array within a document.  The other one deletes the array item entirely.  They both use the .update method in firebase.  They both work as they should (they update the text or they delete the item entirely).  But after using the editing button, my ListView is refreshed.  After deleting an array item, it is not refreshed.
Here are the two buttons:
This one edits the text of a note.
 onPressed: () async {
   Note? newNote = await DialogService()
       .editNoteDialog(context, widget.note, widget.index);
       debugPrint("Got the edited text for the new note.");
       // get all the notes
       List<Note> allNotes = await FilingService().getAllNotes(widget.note.filingId!);
          allNotes[widget.index].note = newNote.note;  // Updates the note text in the list before sending for update.
          FilingService().updateNote(
          allNotes, widget.note.filingId!).then((value) {
          debugPrint("note updated");
          return; 
       });

This one deletes the entire note.
 onPressed: () async {
   bool response = await DialogService().showAlertDialog(
      context, "If you continue, the note will be permanently deleted.");
      if (response) {
      List<Note> allNotes = await FilingService().getAllNotes(widget.note.filingId!);
      allNotes.removeAt(widget.index);  // deletes the note from the list before sending to update.
      FilingService()
      .updateNote(allNotes, widget.note.filingId!).then((value) {
      debugPrint("note deleted");
      return;
      });
      } else {
        debugPrint("note not deleted");
        return;
      }
})

Here is the updateNote method (it just writes the modified list of notes over the old array of notes in Firebase -- I use the same to both update the text and also delete a note):
updateNote (List<Note> notes, String filingId) async {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>>? convertedNotes =[];
  for (int i = 0; i<notes.length; i++) {
    convertedNotes.add(notes[i].toFirestore());
  }
  await _db.collection('filings').doc(filingId).update({
    'notes': convertedNotes}); 

}

Both buttons works as they should.  But only when the note text is changed does it refresh the Stream.  When the entire note is deleted from the array of notes in the Firestore document, even though I'm listening on the entire document in the Stream, it does not refresh the Stream.
I just don't see the difference in the button code ... and the .update method is the same for both.  So I don't see why the delete won't refresh the list also.  Any ideas?

It sounds like the listener isn't retriggering in one of the scenarios. None of the code you shared shows how you call Firestore to read or listen to the data from Firestore though, which makes it hard to say what's going wrong there. Consider if you can reproduce the problem without any of the FilingService indirection, just with direct Firestore API calls and print style logging. (Also see how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example)

@FrankvanPuffelen I think you are right.  I think my streambuilder is not set up right.  The stream checks the filing, but then doesn't use the snapshot to build the ListView.  I'm not sure why it would work with edits, but not deletes.  But therein seems to be the problem.

Good good. If the problem persists, please create a minimal repro (as shown in the link I shared) that shows the exact API calls.

Without looking at your StreamBuilder, we cannot see if (a) you are listening to the stream properly and (b) dealing with deleted items properly by ensuring each item has a ValueKey.

@FrankvanPuffelen.  I ended up rewriting the structure to use a new collection for the Notes.  Then I tied my StreamBuilder to the documents in that collection.  So the original question is moot.  Should I delete it?
